# SQL ISNULL not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull, case-when

I'm trying to display `00001` when the query result is null but the query still return null. I don't know whats wrong with my query.

**EDIT:**

Assuming `OBRNo` is `123-5678-10-13-1619` means `LEN(a.OBRNo) is 19`

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN RIGHT(a.OBRNo, 5) = NULL THEN '00001' ELSE a.OBRNo 
END as CaseWhen, 
ISNULL(a.OBRNo, '00001') as ISNULL,
RIGHT(OBRNo, 5) as OrderBy
FROM tbl_T_BMSCurrentControl as a
WHERE LEN(a.OBRNo) = 20 and a.ActionCode = 1
ORDER BY OrderBy DESC
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder how a NULL result matches `WHERE LEN(a.OBRNo) = 20`

Comment: I would be firstly shure that `a.OBRNo` is not an empty string

Comment: The query doesn't return null - it doesn't return *anything*. `isnull` cannot create rows where there are none. And it can never return any null `a.OBRNo` value, since you're filtering by `len(a.OBRNo) = 20`, which will always be falsy for a null value (and even if it wouldn't, it still certainly wouldn't be 20 :)). You might want to check up on how nulls work in ANSI SQL - it's quite important to get right.

Comment: @Luaan You are right about that. Any way on how to display the default value if that happens ?

Comment: Let your application deal with that. SQL isn't really a good fit for creating relations where there are none :) That's not saying it's impossible, but it's usually a lot more clunky than necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Compare with `NULL` with `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL`, not with `= NULL`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN RIGHT(a.OBRNo, 5) IS NULL THEN '00001' ELSE a.OBRNo END
...
```

You could change this behaviour with [`SET ANSI_NULLS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

The reason why you can't compare with = by default is: `NULL` means undefined. Nothing is equal to unknown not even `NULL`. If you compare with `NULL` the result is unknown, hence also `NULL`.

Comment: I think the question is about another case - `ISNULL(a.OBRNo, '00001') as ISNULL`

Comment: @anatol No, it's about the OP's misunderstanding of the results - he got no results, not a row with nulls. The reason for that is the faulty filter, as Tim points out.

Answer (score 1):

Is your query returning any row?

Your `ISNULL (x,y)` should do what you expect but it looks like your `WHERE` is filtering all the records, due to the `NULLS`.

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN RIGHT(a.OBRNo, 5) = NULL THEN '00001' ELSE a.OBRNo 
END as CaseWhen, 
ISNULL(a.OBRNo, '00001') as ISNULL,
RIGHT(OBRNo, 5) as OrderBy
FROM tbl_T_BMSCurrentControl as a
WHERE (a.OBRNo IS NULL OR LEN(a.OBRNo) = 20) and a.ActionCode = 1
ORDER BY OrderBy DESC
```

`LEN(a.OBRNo)` being `a.OBRNo NULL` will be `NULL` so `NULL = 20` will be `NULL` and `NULL AND a.ActionCode = 1` will be `NULL` which when filtering is treated as `FALSE`